# Is setTimeZone method is device independent?

Tags: android, timezone

My App is heavily dependent on time. If I set the time zone using below code and user device time/date is not set correctly then will it work correctly and return correct time?

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();        
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z"); 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will *not* help if the device time is off. By setting the timezone, you are just telling the formatter to display (what the device thinks is) the current time with an offset of +7/+8 hours.